# what happens to an object in Java if you do not reference it, like here : myString.concat("that")

Tags: java, string, reference

```
String myString = "this";
//string is immutable

myString.concat(" that");
//a new object is created but not assigned to anything

System.out.println(myString); //prints out "this"
```

I would prefer a compile time error - why is this not the case ? The same question can be applied to any method with a return type, when it is called without supplying return type.

```
public myObject doStuff(...whatever){
 //define my method
 return anObject;
}
```

can be called without providing a reference/variable to hold the return type:

```
MyObject newObject = doStuff(); //works
doStuff(); //works too without assigning return object
```

Comment: Instead of asking why it compiles, think of why it should not compile. Can you think of any excuse for it?

Comment: A warning would indeed be appropriate in such cases.

Comment: @Ingo: such a warning would create tons of false positive.

Comment: Use findbug tool : `...ignores return value of String.concat(String)`

Comment: @BoltClock because you can never reference the concatenated string, seems counter-intuitive to me

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Joachim Sauer's answer covers it.

Comment: Joachim, if it's "false positive" then it is, by definition, not the same case, see my comment to your answer.

Comment: @Ingo: I don't understand what you're saying: how should the compiler distinguish if the code ignores the return value of `Collection.add()` vs. `String.concat()`? Should it have a database of all "side-effect free" methods?

Comment: Joachim - he can't distinguish the cases, that's the problem.

Comment: @Ingo: then how is a warning appropriate in this case? If you can't come up with a rule that would *only* warn in this case, but not with `Collection.add()`, then such a warning would be more noise than signal and therefore useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object will be created and eligible for garbage collection right away (i.e. it will probably be garbage collected pretty soon).

The reason this is not a compile time error is that not every method that returns a method requires you to use that return value. Some methods are only called for their side effects.

A good example is [`Collection.add()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29): it returns a `boolean` object, but more often than not, the calling code is not interested in that result and simply ignores it.

Similarly [`StringBuilder.append()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) returns the `StringBuilder` instance so that you can chain the calls. But it's also perfectly valid to ignore that return value and simply use `myStringBuilder.append("foo");`.

Comment: Joachim, you are of course correct, but this exposes yet another weakness of java/API design. It is not possible to distinguish between methods called for their side effect and (more or less pure) functions, i..e. methods called for their return value. If one had this, one could indeed issue useful warnings when the value goes unused.

Comment: @Ingo: pray tell: which language does **not** suffer from this "weakness"? It's the same in C, C++, C#, Python, all BASIC variants and quite a few other languages. The only languages I can think of that *don't* have this "problem" are purely functional ones where the *other* case (methods with side-effects / monads) become very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Java has no built in mechanisms in the method definition headers that would tell the JVM that the method only works on immutable data and the methods only purpose is to output data.

I guess they could create such a language construct, but it would sort of pointlessly clutter up the language without offering a whole lot of tangible benefits IMO.

Comment: This *could* be implemented as an annotation: `@Sideeffect` could indicate methods that have (intended) side effects so ignoring their results can be fine. `@PureFunction` could be used for cases where ignoring the result effectively produces a no-op. Then the IDE/compiler/FindBugs could analyze these annotations (similarly to how `@NonNull` is used in such tools).

Comment: And: I don't think the JVM should care about this. *Only* the compiler or other development tools should use this information, it should not matter to the runtime environment.

Comment: Joachim - you couldn't trust the PureFunction annotation, and you couldn't proove or disproove its truth, therefore, such an annotation would be almost worthless.

Comment: @Ingo: I disagree: you don't need to prove it in the same way that you don't need to prove `@NonNull`: if it's wrong then it's a simple bug in the library, just like any other bug. It would *still* add lots of value. Compare the `@NonNull` annotation: if your code base *consistently* uses this annotation (and the related @Nullable) then code analyzers can give **very good** information on possible `NullPointerException` cases and unnecessary null-checks. Formal verification is a huge increase in complexity from this simple approach and adds comparatively little (in relation to the complexity).

Comment: Joachim - then we will have to agree to disagree. It is telling that today, NullPointerExceptions happen every day in production code, and there is just no way to deal systematically with those "simple bugs in the library". Formal verification is thus extremely valuable IMHO and, btw, would make the whole bunch of code analyzers redundant insofar as they try to tell you something the compiler should be able to tell you.