# Why isn't it necessary to assign a method's return value to a variable?

Tags: java, return-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what happens to an object in Java if you do not reference it, like here : myString.concat(“that”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281160/what-happens-to-an-object-in-java-if-you-do-not-reference-it-like-here-mystri)

```
public class ReturnTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ReturnTest rt = new ReturnTest();
        rt.show();
    }

    public String show()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

In the above code the `show()` method returns a `String` value which is not captured by any variable. Neither the compiler nor the JVM raise any warning, error or exception whatsoever. The same is true for primitive return types. Why?

Shouldn't the compiler make sure that no important value returned by a method is lost by this?

How can i fix this from a shell??

Comment: What if you assign the value to a variable but don't examine it? What if you do examine it, but don't make the "right" decision based on that examination? How far do you want to take this, before the compiler is doing the "right" thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the design of the language.

In many cases, methods returns a value you don't care about. For example `StringBuilder.append()` returns the object itself.

It is true that in some cases an important return value might be lost. For example, `InputStream.skip(long n)` returns the number of bytes skipped. And `read` returns the number of bytes read. There are some tools ([Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)) that detect such bugs. But the language itself doesn't request checking the return value. And even if it did, the program could choose to ignore the value.

Comment: i am not using any IDE, how can i fix this through a shell??

Comment: You can run Checkstyle and FindBugs on the command line or as part of the build. But, why don't you just use an IDE?

Answer (score 5):

Because you don't necessarily need the returned value.

Comment: my question is how does java figured that we don't need the returned value?

Comment: it doesn't. It is just not assigned.

Comment: It's assumed that the programmer knows what they're doing.  If they don't store the returned value, they didn't need it.

Comment: if they don't need the return value they could make it explicit by casting the return value to (void).

Answer (score 4):

You can annotate a method with `@CheckReturnValue` if its return value should always be used. Static code analysis like FindBugs consider this annotation and raise warning when you violate it.

At least this is very reasonable when the method returns some kind of object that needs final processing at the end where the caller is responsible for. This is true for resources that must be closed at the end. Locks that must be released at the end ...

Answer (score 1):

In java functions are not pure, so they may be run for the side effects only. It's just in this case there are no side effects... Consider

```
public String show() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    return "Hello";
}
```

Now would you want a warning? The compiler can't know if you were running it for the side effect or the value, so why insist?