# Why no compilation errors for absentee return types

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return-type

I was trying to understand the concept of method overloading.

```
public class Demo {

    public int myMethod(int num1, int num2) {
        System.out.println("First myMethod of class Demo");
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public double myMethod(double var1, double var2) {
        System.out.println("Second myMethod of class Demo");
        return var1 - var2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Demo obj1 = new Demo();
        //here
        obj1.myMethod(10, 10);
        // and here
        obj1.myMethod(20, 12);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why there is no compilation error for missing return types in **`obj1.myMethod(10, 10);`** and **`obj1.myMethod(20, 12);`** statements.
Clearly both myMethod()s returning int and double.

How come there is no compilation error for that? Please help me to understand.

Comment: you are allowed to ignore the value returned by a method.

Comment: Because there are two overloaded methods with different signatures and you are calling single method two times double means 0.0 floating point values

Comment: This is the java design itself. Refer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782814/why-isnt-it-necessary-to-assign-a-methods-return-value-to-a-variable

Comment: In Java, you are not obliged to handle the return value of the called method and compilation error means that your code misfits the syntax of the programming language. For example you declared an int variable and assigned it by calling methods with double return value and vice versa

Comment: the return types are there, you just don't assign the returned values to variables.

Comment: When an overloaded method is called, the actual method is selected based on the types of the arguments, not the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Both of `myMethod()` return something . You call these methods:

```
obj1.myMethod(10, 10);
obj1.myMethod(20, 12);
```

but you do nothing with that return value. You might want to consider storing return values of these methods in variables, for example:

```
int first = obj1.myMethod(10, 10); //assigning return value of myMethod to int variable
```

Then you can print `first`, to see what was the return value calculated with `myMethod()`:

```
System.out.println(first);
```

Another possibility, instead of storing return value in variable is to print return value to the console directly:

```
System.out.println(obj1.myMethod(10, 10));
```

Note that on both of method calls:

```
obj1.myMethod(10, 10);
obj1.myMethod(20, 12);
```

method returning `int` is being called (`public int myMethod(int num1, int num2) {...}`). This is because you passed `int` arguments to `myMethod()`. If you want the method variant returning double to be called, you can change arguments to `double` values:

```
obj1.myMethod(20.0, 12.0); // here you pass two double values as arguments
```

or:

```
obj1.myMethod((double) 20,(double) 12); // here you cast int values to double
```