# Immutable strings in java?

Tags: java, string, immutability

```
String s = "java";
s.substring(1); // ava
```

Considering the immutability of strings, compiler doesnot modify `'s'` but creates a new object or you can say that there is space for `'java' as well as 'ava'` in memory..

What happens to this `'ava'`, as nothing is pointing to it or it's not being referenced by anything..

One more question... If i would have written `String s = new String("java");` // 'java' is not in string literal pool....

The 'ava' would be in the string literal pool then or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what happens to an object in Java if you do not reference it, like here : myString.concat("that")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281160/what-happens-to-an-object-in-java-if-you-do-not-reference-it-like-here-mystri)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens to this 'ava', as nothing is pointing to it or it's not being referenced by anything..

The newly constructed `String` object immediately becomes eligible for garbage collection.

As to your second question, I don't think there's *any* difference between the following two expressions as far as the string literal pool is concerned:

```
String s = "java";
String s = new String("java");
```

In both cases, the literal `"java"` would be in the pool.  (But in the second case, `s` would not refer to the `"java"` string that's in the pool, but to a different `String` that also has the characters `"java"`.)

Comment: The _only_ strings in the literal pool are those mentioned specifically in a class file in double quotes -- `"java"` itself, for example -- or strings on which `intern()` has been called.

Comment: String a ="aaa";    String b = new String("aaa");----> this will create a new instance of string literal"aaa" as a separate object and put it in the pool as well with another "aaa"

Comment: I think i read somewhere that strings created with new keyword doesnot go into the string literal pool... is this wrong ?

Comment: @rd4code: No, that's correct (that is, unless you `intern()` the String). However -- regardless of how `s` is initialized -- the code that we're discussing contains the literal `"java"`, which does go into the pool.

Comment: @aix i am not able to get it.. what you said is "the code that we are discussing".... String s = "java";
String s = new String("java");  This is the code.... then one java should be in the pool and other should be not ?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Just a clarification. Strings that result from constant expressions are in the pool. These include literal strings (e.g., `"java"`), and strings that are the result of other constant expressions (e.g., `"ja" + "va"`). But these are not the only strings in the pool. Many identifiers find their way in as well (e.g., `C.class.getSimpleName().equals("C")` is true).

Comment: @rd4code: that's correct.  One is in the pool; the other is not.  Think of `new String("java")` as short for `String s1 = "java"; String s2 = new String(s1);`  Then `s1` is in the pool; `s2` is a copy (not in the pool) of `s1`.

Comment: Oops, I mean `C.class.getSimpleName() == "C"` is true. Of course the one involving `equals` is true.

Answer (score 1):

1) What happens to this 'ava', as nothing is pointing to it or it's not being referenced by anything..

As you have not assigned 'ava' to any object means 'ava' is not being pointed by any object so it    would be eligible for garbage collection.

2) The 'ava' would be in the string literal pool then or not ?

```
No it would be in string  literal pool.
```

Comment: String a ="aaa"; String b = new String("aaa");----> this will create a new instance of string literal"aaa" as a separate object and put it in the pool as well with another "aaa"

Answer (score 0):

`s.substring(1)` creates a new `String` pointing to the underlying char array of `s`. The important thing to realise here is that the char array is shared between these two objects. If you use the `String(String)` constructor a *new* char array is created containing the referenced characters.

If you throw away the reference to `s`, if you have a reference to the result of the `substring()` operation then you have a reference to the *full* underlying char array.

In your example you're not storing a reference to the newly created String. So that will be garbage-collected very quickly. The underlying array is still referenced by `s`, however.

Comment: ... however this must be an implementation detail, given the immutability of strings.