# To where does the library functions in c return the value?

Tags: c, function, return-value

Ultimately the library functions will return a value. 
Who captures this returned value?

For example, consider the code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Waiting for a character to be pressed from the keyboard to exit.\n");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

`getch()` returns a value. Who capture this value?

Give me the answer in general sense,not specific to the above program.

Comment: the caller of the function

Comment: it is created and destroyed without anyone noticing. Look at the activation records and stack frames.

Comment: It will be discarded without being simply utilize.

Comment: It's Java, but I couldn't find a C specific duplicate. The concept is the same however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281160/what-happens-to-an-object-in-java-if-you-do-not-reference-it-like-here-mystri

Answer (score 5):

The return value of a function can be discarded.

In the example that you provided, you may not notice that actually `printf` also has a return value.

The function call is evaluated as an **expression statement** in this case, only its side effect is taking place, the return value is discarded. Another example of expression statement is:

```
21 + 21;
```

The expression `21 + 21` is evaluated and discarded. C allows this syntax, although a compiler probably optimized it away.

Comment: The C compiler is indeed very aggressive at optimizing away anything that is effectively a NOP, including function calls that result in no side-effects and whose return values are not stored.

Comment: @aruisdante Which C compiler? It's quite hard for a compiler to know that a function call has no side effects. With the C linkage model, the compiler may not know that the function has no side effects.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: nobody captures the value. The value is simply ignored/discarded.

In your specific example `printf` also returns a value. And it is discarded. Then `getch` returns a value. And it is discarded too. In fact, every expression statement in C language involves discarding a returned value (unless it is a `void` expression).